# Function takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, factorial, ncr

I am writing Python code that calculates nCr. I made a factorial function to use in the process.

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR! Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 16,  in <module> File "<string>", line 13, in nCr TypeError: fact () takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

This is the code:

```py
#function that calculate the factorial
 def fact ():
 mul=1
 num=input ("enter number="))
 for i in range (1, num+1):
     mul=mul*i
 print ("the factorial of the number=",mul)
 fact ()
#function that calculate nCr=
def nCr():
    n=float (input ("enter 1st number(n)="))
    r=float (input ("enter 2nd number(r)="))
    nCr=fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r))
    if n>=r:
        print("the results of the fuction nCr=",nCr)
nCr()
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Note that this is a nice *definition* of the number of combinations, but it's not an efficient way to actually *calculate* it. Consider defining a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) function and implement `nCr` in terms of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding positional arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709025/understanding-positional-arguments-in-python)

Comment: You've defined the function without parameters, but are trying to pass them. That's the source of the error message. Also your indentation is all messed up, you are calling `fact()` within itself for some reason, and you are going to be getting 3 prompts to enter numbers when you run `nCr()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `fact()` does not take any arguments, but you are passing an argument when you call it here: `nCr=fact(n)/(fact(r)*fact(n-r))`

You can fix it like this:

```py
# Function that calculates the factorial
def fact(num):
    mul = 1
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        mul *= i
    return mul

# Function that calculates nCr
def nCr():
    n = int(input("Enter 1st number (n): "))
    r = int(input("Enter 2nd number (r): "))
    
    nCr_value = fact(n) / (fact(r) * fact(n - r))
    if n >= r:
        print("The result of the function nCr =", nCr_value)
    else:
        print("Invalid input: n should be greater than or equal to r")

nCr()  # Call the nCr function
```

Now your function `fact()` only calculates the factorial of the number you pass as an argument. Getting the user input is now done in `nCr()` since it only needs to be done once at the beginning, not each time you calculate a factorial.

I also added the `else` statement to inform the user if they enter invalid input instead of just ending silently.

Comment: Reader caveat: this is a near-verbatim ChatGPT-generated response.